# Write function from encoding/csv pkg stops writting in csv file

Tags: csv, go

I'm trying to extract the names of .txt files in a folder.
But I encounter an issue where the write function from encoding/csv stop writing in the csv file I initialize.
The code is as follow.

```
import (
        "encoding/csv"
        "io/ioutil"
        "log"
        "os"
        "strings"
)

func Extract() error {

    //read folder
    AllFiles, err := ioutil.ReadDir("./folder")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    //create csv file
    SupportCsv, err := os.Create("csvfile.csv")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    WriterSupport := csv.NewWriter(SupportCsv)

    for _, file := range AllFiles {

        res := []string{"test", file.Name()}

        log.Println(res)

        //write in csv file
        err = WriterSupport.Write(res)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
return nil
}
```

I have ~300 .txt file in my folder.
The log.Println prints everything so the issue must be with the Write function.
In return the csv file as less file name and the last name is not written entirely.
Moreover, when i change the number of letter on "test" string in res, the csv file as in return more or less file name in it.
Write returns no error.

Comment: => https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv#Writer.Flush

Comment: Also, don't forget to close your file: `defer SupportCsv.Close()`.

Comment: Thank you @jub0bs everything works find now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you have missed [WriterSupport.Flush()](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/csv#Writer.Flush) after the write. All you need to do is to defer the Flush() to make sure that it is executed. Better after creating `WriterSupport := csv.NewWriter(SupportCsv)`

```
WriterSupport := csv.NewWriter(SupportCsv)
defer WriterSupport.Flush()
```

Comment: No, flushing within the loop most likely isn't what you want. Do it once after of the loop. Better yet: `defer WriterSupport.Flush()` after creating the writer.

Comment: @jub0bs I agree that the flushing within loop is not the right way of doing this. Updated the answer.